# How do I choose a router for fitting doors?

Tags: doors, routers

I need to fit at least 12 doors, 6 of these are fire doors.   So I need to cut out for the hinges on all the doors and frame, as well as fit the Intumescent fire strip in 6 door or frames.

So what do I look for in choosing a router?   (I am in the UK if it makes any difference)

See also [What to look for when picking a router](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27587/what-to-look-for-when-picking-a-router)?, however that question is aimed at hobby wood working, rather then DIY.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a trim router(it will be easier to handle compared to a full sized one), as well as a hinge mortising jig. That's really all to it